# Respond to expect dynamically with the interactive response

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command, expect

I'm looking to use the unix `expect` command to wrap `eb init`.

Here's the API that I'd like.

`eb-init.exp --region=eu-central-1 --app=my-app --env=my-app-live`

Here's the current script that I have:

```
set timeout -1
spawn $env(SHELL)
match_max 100000
send -- "eb init\r"
expect  "Select a default region"
send -- "5\r"
expect "Select an application to use"
send -- "1\r"
expect "Select the default environment"
send -- "1\r"
send -- "exit\r"
expect eof
```

I need a way to interact with the response from expect and string the line with the input argument from the command. For example, if the following is what the command returns it is matched with `expect  "Select a default region"`, I'd like to use the argument `eu-central-1` and get the number 5 and respond dynamically.

```
Select a default region
1) us-east-1 : US East (N. Virginia)
2) us-west-1 : US West (N. California)
3) us-west-2 : US West (Oregon)
4) eu-west-1 : EU (Ireland)
5) eu-central-1 : EU (Frankfurt)
6) ap-south-1 : Asia Pacific (Mumbai)
7) ap-southeast-1 : Asia Pacific (Singapore)
8) ap-southeast-2 : Asia Pacific (Sydney)
9) ap-northeast-1 : Asia Pacific (Tokyo)
10) ap-northeast-2 : Asia Pacific (Seoul)
11) sa-east-1 : South America (Sao Paulo)
12) cn-north-1 : China (Beijing)
(default is 3):
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
set region "eu-central-1"
expect "Select a default region"
expect -re "\[\[:space:]]+(\[0-9]+)\\) $region *:"
expect "(default is *):"
send $expect_out(1,string)\r
```